# Some ideas to increase the visibility of the site and exit the beta stage

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've been an active user of the site from the beginning of the year, and I could say that there was a very nice discovery. It would be even better if we could do something to enlarge the number of users. I think that all people who know or study Latin will appreciate the purpose of the site.

I will post a couple of ideas to increase the visibility of the site:

- promote the site on popular facebook groups, forums or blogs dedicated to ancient Latin and Greek such as [AWOL](http://ancientworldonline.blogspot.com)
- tell friends and colleagues about it
- the most important, I think, is to advertise the site on Universities and High schools

I think that this site is a GREAT opportunity for students of all degree learning latin, but it would be useful or simply enjoyable for teachers and scholars. If I had known it when I was a young student it would had been a great opportunity to improve my translation skills, my linguistic competences as well as my proficiency in English.

Comment: (1) I'm glad that you joined us and enjoy the site! You are not alone with that joy. (2) I would have loved to have something like this as a student, too. Now this is a good way to keep my Latin active. My day job is unrelated. (3) Have you looked at earlier questions tagged [meta-tag:site-promotion]? There have been similar ideas. (4) Do you have concrete ideas for promoting the site? What kind of feedback are you looking for? I agree with the sentiment, but I'm not sure what kinds of responses you would like to see.

Comment: (5) I am still going to finish [that article](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/203/79), but I need to finish some other writing projects at work before it feels appropriate. (6) If you know suitable people, mailing lists, or other, feel free to promote the site! I have done so on several occasions, and will continue. Organizing site promotion collaboration is a bit tricky. (7) One of the best things we could have is a good [flier](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/223/79) or something similar to be distributed as an advertisement. Ideas about that would be welcome!

Comment: In case you are interested but haven't noticed, we have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm). If you want to talk about the site or Latin without the Q&A format, you are welcome to drop in. This invitation applies to everyone, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have in mind mainly to promote the site among high schools and university students, in order to support a reference point for an active study of Latin. The idea of the flier or poster is good, and I think that together with the article it could be a great way to advertise the site.

Comment: Hi Alessio. You mentioned leaving Beta, but do you have any idea when that should be? Looking at other Beta sites, it seems very inconsistent.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I have understood that site graduation considered case by case but there is a rule of thumb for the activity requirement: the site should have consistently at least ten questions per day. If you want to know the exact criteria and how close our site is to them, I suggest asking a separate meta question.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer [This is the list of sites that most recently left beta status](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched).  If you click on each one you'll see that there isn't really one particular number that predicts graduation, and that we probably have a long ways to go.

Comment: @Nathaniel That's what I had noticed. I was hoping from the title of the question there was something that I didn't know.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer seeing these statistics I have noticed that what actually lacks is a larger user-base. This is the reason why I suggested about some opportunity to advertise the site. The flier is a good idea, when it will be ready It could be useful to send it to high schools and universities

Comment: I agree that growing the user base is the most important thing. With more users there will be more questions and answers, and consequently more content for people to find through search engines.